# Paint not "ticking" fast enough, and leaving dots

Tags: java, graphics

I'm attempting to make a little paint app where you input the color you want, and change the size of the brush. I did this, and it works, but if I try to paint quickly, the app doesn't update for a short period of time, leaving dots looking like this: [image: Paint Demo]

60 times per second (because 60 times per second *should* be enough to not leave dots/gaps. See tick method. As a test, I tried putting *no* limit on the ticksPerSecond, and I got the same output), if the user is causing a `mouseDragged` or `mousePressed` event, I add a an instance of the `Circle` class (seen below)

```
class Circle {
    int x, y;
    int radius;
    Color color;

    Circle(int x, int y, int radius, Color color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

My tick method: (Called 60 times each second)

```
private void tick() {
    this.middle = this.brush.radius / 2; // Used because java.awt.Graphics will paint from your cursors xy, which will paint the circle down and to the right of the cursor

    if (this.frame.isDragging) {
        add(new Circle(this.frame.x - this.middle, this.frame.y - this.middle, this.brush.radius, this.brush.color));
    }
}
```

To render, I just run through a `foreach` loop, seen below

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); // Paint over everything else

    try {
        for (Circle circle : this.circles) {
            g.setColor(circle.color);
            g.fillOval(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, circle.radius);
        }
    } catch (ConcurrentModificationException ignore) {} //TODO MAKE THIS BETTER
}
```

Ignore that I'm catching a `ConcurrentModifictionException`, this is a temporary fix because I'm adding to a list that's being read here. (It only causes the paint to flash while I am painting, so it works for now)

I was asked for my Frame, here it is (You probably don't need this, but I included any code you needed. I remove `implement methods` that I didn't use):

```
class Frame extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

int x, y;
boolean isDragging, isMouseOnScreen;

Frame(int width) {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, width / 3 * 2));
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.pack();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Cursor cursor = this.getToolkit().createCustomCursor(image, new Point(0, 0), "Cursor");
    this.setCursor(cursor);

    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.requestFocus();
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);

    this.x = this.y = 0;
    this.isDragging = this.isMouseOnScreen = false;
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    this.x = e.getX() - 5;
    this.y = e.getY() - 35;
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    this.x = e.getX() - 5;
    this.y = e.getY() - 35;
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    this.isDragging = true;
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    this.isDragging = false;
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    isMouseOnScreen = true;
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    isMouseOnScreen = false;
}
}
```

Comment: You need to draw a "line" of brushes between the points to fill in the gaps.  As a guess, it seems that mouseDragged() is not being called fast enough.  Where are you setting `frame`?

Comment: You could be able to move the mouse by several 100 or even 1000s of pixels per second so gaps could happen, especially if you want to draw fine _lines_ (that should already be a hint: don't draw dots/circles but lines between mouse positions). Additionally the rate at which mouse events are fired might be lower than the rendering rate, i.e. you might have a lot fewer than 60 mouse events per second.

Comment: How would I draw a line? I'm assuming that lines are straight, yet people can "curve" their lines.

I added my Frame class, didn't simplify it though.

I know that my issue isn't solely the fast that the mouse is moving 1000's of pixels in a second because I've tried putting no limit of how many ticks per second.

It shouldn't matter if I get less than 60 mouse events, because it only updates my isDragging variable.

Comment: You can draw line between current point and the previous.

Comment: You can draw curves too, to avoid angles. There is algorythms on the internet about that.